# Implement Goldbach's conjecture in Haskell

Tags: haskell, primes, goldbach-conjecture

So Goldbach's conjecture says that every positive even number greater than 2 is the sum of two prime numbers. I am trying to write a Haskell program that will, given a positive even integer, find those 2 prime numbers:

```
goldbach n = head [(x,y) | x <- primesR 2 (n-1),
                           let y = n-x-1, isPrime y]
```

Where `primesR` is given below as (returns primes in range):

```
primesR :: Integral a => a -> a -> [a]
primesR a b = takeWhile (<= b) $ dropWhile (< a) $ sieve [2..]
  where sieve (n:ns) = n:sieve [ m | m <- ns, m `mod` n /= 0 ]
```

However, this doesn't consistently give me the correct prime numbers. I think my indexing is off but I'm not sure how/where?

Comment: What's the definition of `primesR`? Give an example of an input value (and the output) which are not what you expect. Note that `x+y` will always equal `n-1`.

Comment: @ErikR oops sorry left that definition out. I have edited the question!

Comment: I think it's just the definition of `y` - isn't this supposed to be `let y = n-x` (IMO you want `x+y = n`)?  - seems ok for me as `goldbach 16 = (3,13)` for example (yes I saw that ErikR basically has the same remark - but it seems as OP has not connected the dots or we both are wrong)

Comment: @Carsten you are right! I corrected the code and it worked great! Silly mistake ;)

Comment: well then either you or @ErikR should probably give an answer or you should close the question (it's just a slight mistake really)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

turns out the problem is a small *logical* mistake:

```
goldbach n = head [(x,y) | x <- primesR 2 (n-1),
                           let y = n-x, isPrime y]
```

as `n` is supposed to be `x+y` it should be `let y=n-x` instead